I can not able to use passport in laravel. when I run this command "php artisan passport:install"
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\passport2> php artisan passport:install
ERROR  Encryption keys already exist. Use the --force option to overwrite them.
INFO  Publishing [passport-migrations] assets.
Copying directory [C:\xampp\htdocs\passport2\vendor\laravel\passport\database\migrations] to [C:\xampp\htdocs\passport2\database\migrations]  DONE
Would you like to run all pending database migrations? (yes/no) [yes]:

yes

INFO  Running migrations.
2024_04_18_201730_create_oauth_auth_codes_table ..................................................................................... 13.65ms FAIL
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'oauth_auth_codes' already exists (Connection: mysql, SQL: create table oauth_auth_codes ( id varchar(100) not null, user_id bigint unsigned not null, client_id bigint unsigned not null, scopes text null, revoked tinyint(1) not null, expir es_at datetime null, primary key (id)) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:813
809▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
810▕                 );
811▕             }
812▕
➜ 813▕             throw new QueryException(
814▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
815▕             );
816▕         }
817▕     }
1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:571
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'oauth_auth_codes' already exists")
2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:571
PDOStatement::execute()
I can not able to solve this error. I have checked database throw the phpmyadmin where database is visible and there are all tables present. but I don't no why is throwing the error.

All the errors seem to be saying that things already exist, so maybe you already did this successfully, and don't need to do it again?
